# Java regex to remove specific punctuation

Tags: java, regex, formatting, replaceall

I'm formatting a very large amount of plaintext files using java, and I need to remove all punctuation except for apostrophes. When I originally had set up the regex for the `replaceAll` statement, it worked to get rid of everything that I knew of, except now I've found one particular file/punctuation set that it's not working in.

```
    holdMe = holdMe.replaceAll("[,_\"-.!?:;)(}{]", " ");
```

I know I'm hitting this statement because all of the other punctuation clears, there's no periods, commas, etcetera. I've tried escaping out the () and {} characters, but it still doesn't get replaced on those characters. I've been trying to teach myself regex using the Oracle documentation, but I can't seem to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: You are going to have to show some samples of input and output.

Comment: The question wouldn't let me include the text that I'm having an issue with, it was recognizing as code, so here's the problem text. The output comes out the same as the input.
**
We do it for them niggas that live on parole 
(My street corner duns that put glass in they gold) {we always gonna do it} 
Even if I'm locked {we still gon' do it} 
(And old guns on the block) {we still gon' do it} 
To the neighborhood cops {we still gon' do it} 
{We still gon' do it, we always gon' do it}**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regex will mark every punctuation except Apostrophes

```
[\p{P}&&[^\u0027]]
```

---

The java-string of the regex:

```
"[\\p{P}&&[^\u0027]]"
```

Comment: This answer would be perfect, except that the question is asking to exclude apostrophes, which are `\x27`, not double-quote characters or NULs.

Comment: You can go a step farther and simply use the `'` character directly in the regular expression, which should make it easier to understand.

Comment: That's the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifically specifying every single character you want removed - why not do the opposite, and state which you want to allow, and prefix it with a not?

```
holdMe = holdMe.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9'\\s]+"," ");
```

The above will replace everything other than white spaces, alphanumeric characters, and apostrophes with `" "`.

Comment: Had to add another \ to escape the \s, but it still does not replace the {} and () characters in this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* use \\ (double) before { } [ ] */
        String m = "this:{[]}/; is a test".replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\{\\}\\/,_\"-.!?:;)(]", " ");
        System.out.println(m);
    }
```

Output:

```
this        is a test
```