# how to remove all punctuation from a string except for apostrophy

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I'm trying to figure out the correct way to remove all punctuation and white-space from a string but leave apostrophes intact so for example:

*won't* would remain *won't* but "*desire.*" would turn into "*desire*"

I've tried using `replaceAll("[\\W]", ""), replaceAll("/\\p{P}(?<!')/", ""), and replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "")` but they all leave the punctuation fully intact

Comment: `but they all leave the punctuation fully intact` Are you reassigning the string variable? [Strings are immutable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450519/why-does-string-replace-not-work), so you need to reassign the string each time you call `replaceAll`.

Comment: Try `s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{P}&&[^']]", "")`

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\']", "");`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java regex to remove specific punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741797/java-regex-to-remove-specific-punctuation)

Answer (score -2):

```
String s = "don't.";
s = s.replaceAll("(')|(\\W)", "$1");
```

Comment: `\w` character class includes the underscore class. Therefore, [your solution doesn't work](http://ideone.com/0u811d).

Comment: @BackSlash The user did not mention anything related to the underscore. He said he wants to remove punctuation and white space which are both included in the \W class.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) Underscore is listed as a punctuation mark used in general typography. Also, the OP was trying to match `\p{P}` in his regex, and [that pattern includes underscore](http://ideone.com/h9eLlY).

Comment: @BackSlash The 3 instructions he mentioned all have different results, and none of them achieve what he wants. The first one he posted was supposed to achieve exactly what I said. If he really wants to remove underscore, he can simply add (_) as third capturing group and it will be removed. If the user feels this does not achieve what he's trying to do he can always reply and enlighten us.